# What is a description along the bottom of a video generally called?

Tags: after-effects, terminology

Sorry about the terrible title question. I'll edit it if I get an answer to be more useful to others, or you're welcome to do so.

I'm trying to find tutorials and even inspiration for stuff like the DKS bar in this picture:

[image: image from video]

I looked up "trade show videos" "after effects titles" "after effects text" and haven't really found much that's helping. Is there a name used in the video world for that part of a video which might help me find more examples?

Here's the video set to this moment so you can see it all animated:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is often called a lower third because it is a bar often appearing in the lower third of the image.  Also sometimes a name plate or title plate.

Comment: Thanks looking up "designing lower third after effects" found a bunch of results

Answer (score 2):

Things like this are called TG or Title Graphics